# Given a 2D matrix of characters we have to check whether the given word exist in it or not

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D matrix of characters we have to check whether the given word exist in it or not. 
eg

```
 s f t 
 d a h 
 r y o
```

we can find "rat in it 
**(top down , straight ,diagonal or anypath**).. even in **reverse order**. with least complexiety.

my approach is

```
While traversing the 2d matrix ( a[][] ) row wise. 
If ( a[i][j] == first character of given word ) { 
    search for rest of the letters in 4 directions i.e. right, right diagonally down, down and left diagonally down. 
} else if( a[i][j] == last character of the given word ) { 
    search for remaining characters in reverse order in 4 directions i.e. left, right diagonally up, up, left diagonally up. 
}
```

is there any better approach?

Comment: What the best approach is depends in part on the rules for words, which you haven't stated clearly enough for the problem to be solvable.  Do letters of a word have to be in a straight line, or will any path do?  Can a path cross itself, and/or reuse letters?  Also, two different O() functions apply: one for preprocessing, one for searching.  After preprocessing, you might look for rare letters or rare tuples first

Comment: An important question here is:What is the maximum length of the word to be searched?That can change the whole story.

Answer (score 2):

Let me describe a very cool data structure for this problem.

Go ahead and look up Tries.

It takes O(k) time to insert a k-length word into the Trie, and O(k) to look-up the presence of a k-length word.

[Video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfqS5nUH9ew)

If you have problems understanding the data structure, or implementing it, I'll be happy to help you there.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that there are no duplicates?

Comment: The OP asked to check for presence, not count, but the latter can easily be fixed.If you implement a trie, it's just a little modification to that code.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I meant duplicate letters, not duplicate strings. For example, wouldn't a trie detect the word `bat` in the following matrix: `[b n t; a x a; f p j]`?

Comment: No it wouldn't.We construct the trie based on rules specified in the problem.So the trie will consist of only valid words that can be formed from the matrix.

Comment: Link is dead, it seems!!

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have 16 sequences here:

```
sft
dah
ryo
sdr
fay
tho
sao
rat
tfs
had
oyr
rds
yaf
oht
oas
tar
```

(3 horizontal + 3 vertical + 2 diagonals) * 2 (reversed) = 16. Let n be a size of a matrix. In your example n = 3. Number of sequences = (n + n + 2) * 2 = 4n + 4.

Now you need to determine whether a sequence is a word or not. Create a hash set (`unordered_set` in C++, `HashSet` in Java) with words from dictionary (found on the internet). You can check one sequence in O(1).

Comment: 'Any path' is not accurate term at all. What is the length of the path? Can it overlap? With 'any' path all I can say you will have 'any' complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do this in two phases:

1) Iterate over the array, looking for instances of the first letter in the word.

2) Whenever you find an instance of the first letter, call a function that examines all adjacent cells (e.g. up to 9 of them) to see if any of them are the second letter of the word.  For any second-letter-matches that are found, this function would call itself recursively and look for third-letter matches in cells adjacent to that (and so on).  If the recursion ever gets all the way to the final letter of the word and finds a match for it, then the word exists in the array.  (Note that if you're not allowed to use a letter twice you'll need to flag cells as 'already used' in order to prevent the algorithm from re-using them.  Probably the easiest way to do that would be to pass-by-value a vector of already-used-cell-coordinates in to the recursive function, and have the recursive function ignore the contents of any cells that are in that list)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the first letter or your word using a simple loop and when you find it use the following recursive function.

The function will get as input 5 parameters: the word you are looking for `str`, your current position of the letter in the word `str` you look for in your array `k`, `i` and `j` as the position in your array to search for the letter and direction `d`.

The stop conditions will be:

-if `k > strlen(str); return 1;`

-if `arr[i][j] != str[k]; return 0;`

If none of the upper statements are true you increment your letter counter `k++`; update your `i` and `j` acording to your value of `d` and call again your function via `return func(str, k);`